# Absolutely continuous implies Lipschitz on compact subsets?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lipschitz-functions, absolute-continuity

Let $f$ be absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, then is it Lipschitz on all compact subsets of $(a,b)$?

---

I am not able to prove or disprove it.

My attempt to disprove: The favorite example $f(x)=\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$ doesn't seem to work here since it is Lipschitz on compact subsets of $(0,1)$. (bounded derivatives on compact subset)

My attempt to prove:
\begin{align*}
|f(y)-f(x)|&=\left|\int_x^y f'(t)\,dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_x^y |f'(t)|\,dt
\end{align*}

I am unable to proceed since $f'$ is not necessarily bounded.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{x}$ will work, but consider it in an interval larger than $(0,1)$.

**Edit:** So, we consider $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{c l} 0, &-1\leq x\leq 0 \\ \sqrt{x}, & 0<x\leq 2\end{array}\right..$$ Then $f$ is differentiable on $(-1,2)\setminus\{0\}$, with $$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{c l} 0, &-1<x<0 \\ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}, & 0<x<2\end{array}\right.,$$ which is in $L^1\left([-1,2]\right)$, and $$f(x)=f(-1)+\int_{-1}^xf'(t)\,dt$$ for all $x\in[-1,2]$. Therefore $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[-1,2]$. However, $f$ is not Lipschitz on $[0,1]$: if it was, then, for some $M>0$ and all $x\in[0,1]$, $$\sqrt{x}=|f(x)-f(0)|\leq M|x-0|=Mx\Rightarrow M\sqrt{x}\geq 1,$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. But any lower than 0 will lead to square root of a negative number, which is undefined right? E.g. $\sqrt x$ on $[-\epsilon, 2]$?

Comment: Try defining it differently for $x<0$.

Comment: Nice. I am trying $f(x)=\sqrt x$ on $[0,2]$, $f(x)=0$ on $[-1,0]$.

Comment: Right; this will be continuous on $[-1,2]$, and not Lipschitz on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Since your answer does not really answer the original question, perhaps you should rewrite to reflect the comments.

Comment: Ok, I just did.